# A value of type 'Stream<User?>' can't be returned from the function 'user' because it has a return type of 'Stream<User>' in flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a getter, but it is showing me this error on last line in the below code snippet.

The code is -

```
class AuthRepository extends BaseAuthRepository {

  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore;
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthRepository({
    FirebaseFirestore? firebaseFirestore,
    auth.FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth,
  })  : _firebaseFirestore = firebaseFirestore ?? FirebaseFirestore.instance,
        _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  // TODO: implement user
  Stream<auth.User> get user => _firebaseAuth.userChanges();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
Stream<auth.User?> get user => auth.userChanges();
```

Comment: On the "user", it is showing this error - 'AuthRepository.user' ('Stream<User?> Function()') isn't a valid override of 'BaseAuthRepository.user' ('Stream<User> Function()').

Comment: It might be issue with your extended class `BaseAuthRepository`, bcs above line is the perfect with the null safety

Comment: Yes, it was. I really forgot about that. Thanks to you bro.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 Stream<auth.User> get user => _firebaseAuth.userChanges();
```

to

```
Stream<auth.User> get user => _firebaseAuth.userChanges()!;
```

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/userChanges.html),

The method returns an object of Stream<User?>, which means that it may be null.

Since you can't be sure of the contents of the type returned, instead of returning it, you can check if it is null.

I.E.

```
class AuthRepository extends BaseAuthRepository {

final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore;
final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

AuthRepository({
  FirebaseFirestore? firebaseFirestore,
  auth.FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth,
  })  : _firebaseFirestore = firebaseFirestore ?? FirebaseFirestore.instance,
    _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;

 @override
 // TODO: implement user
 Stream<auth.User> get user => 
   val userChanges = _firebaseAuth.userChanges();
   if (userChanges != null) return userChanges
   else //your logic
```

Comment: No. it is again giving the same error. In your code snippet, return userChanges is giving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

`_firebaseAuth.userChanges()` returns `User?` which is nullable so you need to update your return type to be nullable by adding `?` after `auth.User` like below:

```dart
  Stream<auth.User?> get user => _firebaseAuth.userChanges();
```

Comment: Actually I tried it, but i got this error on "user" in the line, you mentioned. This is the error -AuthRepository.user' ('Stream<User?> Function()') isn't a valid override of 'BaseAuthRepository.user' ('Stream<User> Function()').

Comment: You need to make the same change in your `BaseAuthRepository`

Comment: Please read the guide to migrate to null safety: https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Comment: I really forgot about that. I made the changes and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This it worked for me:

```dart
Stream<auth.User?> get user => _firebaseAuth.userChanges();
```

It sends out events when a user's credentials are linked or unlinked, as well as when the user's profile is updated. This Stream's goal is to listen to real-time changes to the user state (signed-in, signed-out, different user & token refresh) without having to manually perform reload and then return changes to your application.

Check the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/userChanges.html) for more information.